Handling large amount of page on a site
We are building our intranet in SharePoint, and one thing we still struggle with is, how to handle large amount of Pages in a site. We have broke down the contents to different as much as it is possible for us currently, but still often find that we have 50+ pages on a site.
Relying only on the Site Pages library is far from being user friendly, creating pages with highlighted contents web parts and pulling the pages via metadata requires extreme amount of custom metadata added, as well as the pages are not anchored nowhere in the navigation it leaves the users completely without a sense where they are exactly and how to navigate quickly.
Every guide and information talks about the above examples, but none seems to show a working example/module, which could be satisfying with large amount of pages.
What's the best practice, how do other organizations manage this boundaries?
